# add connection string at runtime

Tags: asp.net, web-config

Is it possible to insert a connection string into a web.config file at runtime, if it isn't there? Would this work?

The connection string is for a ASP.NET user login and create account database.

Comment: Do you want to manually or programatically add the connection string?

Comment: The solution I provided is what you're looking for. I added further explanation for your convenience :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you mean "insert?"  If you mean can you manually edit web.config: yes, you can.  You'd add an entry for connectionStrings (if there wasn't one) an then a child node for your specific connectionString.

If you mean can you do it in code: theoretically yes.  However, it is normally bad practice, and a pain the rear.

Comment: If you needed to be able to switch connectionstring at runtime you could chuck it into a database instead of web.config

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is very possible:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="yourNameHere" connectionString="connectiongStringHere" providerName="nameHere"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

inside ConfigSections

Comment: Thanks, but in the 'add name="yourNameHere" , what would the name be?

Comment: It's the name you would give to the connection string, to later make reference to it.

You could use ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["yourNameHere"].ConnectionString to retrieve it.

Answer (score 0):

Put a default connectionstring in your web.config and replace the username/password and database name at runtime as desired.